# Why is the infinite union of cofinite sets necessarily cofinite with regard to the cofinite topology of the reals?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The open sets of the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$ are defined as all sets in $\mathbb{R}$ whose complement is finite.  Can someone point out the error in my logic with regards to the union of any open sets also being open?

Let:
$$U = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{U_i \mid \mathbb{R} - i\}$$
So for example, $U_1 = \mathbb{R} - 1$, $U_2 = \mathbb{R} - 2$, etc. Thus each $U_i \in U$ is cofinite and in the set of open sets.

However, isn't the set $U$ not cofinite since $U = \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{N}$ meaning the complement of $U$ is $\mathbb{N}$ which is not finite?

Comment: You're mixing up unions and intersections. What you've shown is that the countable intersection of cofinite sets needn't be cofinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more sets you throw into a union, the smaller the complement becomes. In your example, $U_1 \cup U_2 = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

$(\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}) \cup (\Bbb R\setminus\{2\})=\Bbb R$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of open sets, which means their complements are either finite or $\mathbb{R}$. Proving that
$$
U=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i
$$
is open is the same as showing that the complement is closed (that is, either finite or $\mathbb{R}$); now, by De Morgan,
$$
\mathbb{R}\setminus U=\mathbb{R}\setminus\biggl(\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i\biggr)=
\bigcap_{i\in I}(\mathbb{R}\setminus U_i)
$$
If one of the $U_i$, say $U_{i_0}$ is non empty, we have
$$
\bigcap_{i\in I}(\mathbb{R}\setminus U_i)\subseteq
\mathbb{R}\setminus U_{i_0}
$$
which is finite. Otherwise every $U_i$ is empty and the union is empty, thus open.